# Add function to ~/.zshrc

Tags: zsh, visual-studio-code, c++, compile, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to apply the following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549853/compiling-header-files-for-c-using-vscode-code-runner

But I'm stuck/missdo on the part to copy and paste the function cppcompile when I open

`sudo code ~/.zshrc`

Because after following all the steps when I try to compile my program I got the following :

`bash: cppcompile: command not found`

So how to add a function to ~/.zshrc? (Personally, I just copy and paste it as it said, or maybe there is a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.zshrc` is executed when you open a new shell. Changes in it don't affect existing shells automatically. So either:

- Open a new shell, or
- Use the command `. ~/.zshrc` (yes, it starts with a dot followed by a space) to execute the file again in your current shell